# (weird) Explanations in Xenakis' Formalized Music

Tags: probability, notation, music-theory

First time posting on MSE, very nervous. Been lurking for a long time.

I've been looking through Formalized Music (Xenakis) and building software around the ideas in the book. Upon thorough inspection, some of the descriptions in the annex are written in a style that I'm not very used to.

I've tried digging around for more of this, but no one seems to really talk about it with enough rigor.

He writes:

> **Second Law**

> $f(j) dj = \frac{2}{a}(1-\frac{j}{a})dj$

> Each variable (pitch, intensity, density, etc.) forms an interval (distance) with its predecessor. Each interval is identified with a segment $x$ taken on the axis of the variable. Let there be two points $A$ and $B$ on this axis corresponding to the lower and upper limits of the variable. It is then a matter of drawing at random a segment within $AB$ whose length is included between $j$  and $j + dj$ for $0 \leq j \leq AB$. Then the probability of this event is:

> $P_j = f(j)dj = \frac{2}{a}(1-\frac{j}{a})dj$ , for $a = AB$.

I can't really seem to picture how this will be the case, and I'm not really understanding the notation of "_j" in this case for P. I assume dj is an arbitrary point away from point j, and so the function takes an input of a coordinate(?).

I appreciate any help at all in advance! Thank you.

Comment: This book is new to me but browsing it just for a few minutes it looks amazing. $P_j$ just means that the probability $P$ depends on the point $j$ where the segment $[j,j+dj]$ starts. You may want to start with simpler literature (perhaps even Wikipedia) about continuous probability distribution functions and probability densities.

Comment: Thank you so much. I haven't seen continuous PDFs in this form before. I would assume something like $\int_a^b f(x) dx$. I think I'm also not clear on what he is trying to say.

Comment: Ah okay I see it now. It could be written as: $p(a \leq j \leq b) = \int_a^b f(j)dj$ The notation throws me off.